# How to remove unneeded rpm packages in openSUSE?

Tags: package-management, opensuse, rpm, zypper

Is there any alternatives for `yum autoremove` in `rpm` or `zypper`? (openSUSE doesnt have yum)

I need it because zypper installs recommended packages by default and often doesnt clean them automatically

Comment: As a long-term fix, you could also consider changing your install options so that you only install the depending packages alongside the desired ones instead of the recommended (and maybe the suggested) ones also.

Answer (score 3):

as an addition to the answer by Chris:

check the lists in

`zypper packages --installed-only --suggested`

and

`zypper packages --installed-only --recommended`

most likely there is some stuff pulled-in by recommended/suggested deps which is "unneeded" for your particular configuration

Answer (score 2):

`zypper` doesn't seem to have an exact match, but:

To remove a package with its (unneeded) dependencies:

```
zypper rm --clean-deps <package>
```

To find packages that are probably not needed anymore:

```
zypper packages --unneeded
```

Answer (score 0):

If asking dependencies to uninstall a single package. Then run below command. It will skip dependencies and only target rpm will remove only.

```
rpm -e packagename --nodeps
```

Comment: This explained how to forcibly remove a package, which isn’t what the question is asking.